# Zip file extraction fails while installing

Tags: unzip, install4j

Using Install4j trying to prepare a Window GUI installer. After Installer generation when installation process starts it throws a exception from install4j itself.

Log included below.

```
  Download: http://someurl.com/packages/jdk/jdk-6u43-win-x86/jdk.zip to c:\packages\jdk.zip; size: 92416142 bytes 
       Execute action successful after 6561 ms 
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.ExtractZipFileAction [ID 67]: Execute action 
       Property mode: 644 
       Property showProgress: true 
       Property destinationDirectory: installed_software 
       Property dirMode: 755 
       Property fileFilter: null 
       Property zipFile: packages\jdk.zip 
       Property rollbackSupported: true 
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.ExtractZipFileAction [ID 67]: exception java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\installed_software\jdk\bin\msvcr71.dll (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) 
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\dfdeploy\installed_software\jdk\bin\msvcr71.dll (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\installed_software\jdk\bin\msvcr71.dll (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process) 
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) 
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194) 
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145) 
 at com.exe4j.runtime.util.FileUtil.extractFile(Unknown Source) 
 at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.ExtractZipFileAction.createFile(Unknown Source) 
 at com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.AbstractExtractZipFileAction.extractZip(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you updating an existing installation? It seems like the JDK that you're installing is currently being executed. In that case, you cannot overwrite all of its files.

Comment: Yea you are correct, the problem happens while executing same installer twice. Thanks @IngoKegel